# 'unused arguments' error in mediation package R

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a mediation analysis on my dissertation data. I have my DV/outcome variable (attitudes2), predicted by condition type and attitudes 1, plus random effect (participant number), mediated by shared oppression.

I created the mediator model (med.fit) and outcome model (out.fit) as follows:

```r
med.fit <- lm(shared oppression ~ condition type + participant number) 
out.fit <- lm(attitudes2 ~ condition type + participant number + shared oppression
```

I then inputted this into the mediation package as per the info on the mediation package R documentation:

```
med.out<- (med.fit, out.fit, treat="condition type", mediator = "shared oppression", robustSE = TRUE, sims = 100)
```

This results in the following error message:

> Error in mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat = "data1$Condition.Type", mediator = "data1$Shared.Oppression",  : 
>     unused arguments (treat = "data1$Condition.Type", mediator = "data1$Shared.Oppression", robustSE = TRUE, sims = 100)

I'm not sure how to fix this or if I've inputted anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue would be related to the spaces in the column names.  It can be corrected by wrapping with backquotes (`)

```
library(mediation)
med.fit <- lm(`shared oppression` ~ `condition type` +
           `participant number`, data = data1) 
out.fit <- lm(attitudes2 ~ `condition type` + `participant number` +   
            `shared oppression`, data = data1)

med.out<- mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat="condition type",
          mediator = "shared oppression", robustSE = TRUE, sims = 100)
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
data(jobs)
names(jobs)[1] <- "treat type"
b <- lm(job_seek ~ `treat type` + econ_hard + sex + age, data=jobs)
c <- lm(depress2 ~ `treat type` + job_seek + econ_hard + sex + age, data=jobs)

# Estimation via quasi-Bayesian approximation
contcont <- mediate(b, c, sims=50, treat="treat type", mediator="job_seek")

contcont$d0
#[1] -0.0128006
```

Comment: Hi - sorry, I didn't use my actual data names in that code for ease of understanding the variables. The actual data names are data$shared.oppression~data$condition.type etc. so would this still be an issue?

Comment: @eleanor_lh I believe the `data$` is not part of the column name.  If it is, then it is. highly reocmmended to backquote because `$` is one operator to extract the column value from a dataset

Comment: I wrapped the column names in backquotes as in your example, using the data=data1 instead of $ but it is still returning the error message "unused arguments"

Comment: @eleanor_lh without a reproducible example, it is not clear about your issue.  I have tested this code on a reproducible dataset

Comment: I think there must be a problem with my package or with my data, but thank you for all your help!